# JTable - make one of the headers behave differently on click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader, rowsorter

I have a simple JTable:

```
    String[] columnNames = {"Freetext",
                            "Numbers only",
                            "Combobox"};

    Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", new Integer(21), "Female"},
    {"John", new Integer(19), "Male"},
    {"Sue", new Integer(20), "Female"},
    {"Joe", new Integer(22), "Male"}
    };

    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    TableColumn comboboxCol = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("Male");
    comboBox.addItem("Female");
    comboboxCol.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));       
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new IntegerEditor(0, 100));
```

When I click on the colum header, it will alternate between ascending and descending sorting. I would like to add one more column header that will act differently on click, with other headers retaining their behaviour. How would you do that?

Comment: `I would like to add one more column header that will act differently on click` - define act differently.

Comment: Its been a couple of hours since I asked for clarification on the requirement.

Comment: I want it to have completely different action - NOT extended action of sorter, for example I want to open a Message Dialog on click on that ONE header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`: This action defines a row sorter that is an instance of `TableRowSorter`. This provides a table that does a simple locale-specific sort when the user clicks on a column header. You can specify sort order and precedence of the column for sorting using `SortKeys`:

```
TableRowSorter sorter = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter();
List <RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("aColumnID"), SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("bColumnID"), SortOrder.UNSORTED));
 // to specify no sorting should happen on 'bColumnID'
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
```

Again, **If you want to specify event on the specific column, for example column with id `bColumnID`**:

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     super.mouseClicked(e); 
     JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader)(e.getSource());  
     JTable tableView = header.getTable();  
     TableColumnModel columnModel = tableView.getColumnModel();  
     int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX()); 

      if(columnModel.getColumn(viewColumn).getIdentifier().equals("bColumnID"))
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi bColumnID header is clicked");
      }

      }


});
```

**Edit:**

however, I understood you wrong `(that upon one of the column header click you want the table unsorted and do other action) but as @camickr has made that clear`, use: `sorter.setSortable(index, boolean)`.

More formally, for turning off sorting for specific column with column identifier e.g., `"bColumnName"`:

```
sorter.setSortable(table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("bColumnName"), false);
```

to disable sorting for column with identifier `"bColumnName"`.

Comment: @jzd, Thanks, a dumb netbeans 7 IDE user :)

Comment: No problem.   I think this is the correct answer for the question as stated.  I am leaving my answer up as I think it might be useful if you want to change the look or do something more drastic.

Comment: @lukasseveryn, SortKeys does not prevent sorting of a specific column. It only contains the current sorting state of the model and it can be changed at any time.

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of change of sorting behaviour on click and only display the dialog?

Comment: @camickr, thanks for correcting me. I was interpreted the OP's question wrong.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, i have updated the answer for you with code snippet and disabling sorting with column `name` with the help of `camickr` answer in which he introduced the function for disabling sorting with column `index`

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, `thanks so much everyone who contributed!` - and yet I didn't even get a simple up vote even though I provided the complete answer. I was the only one who understood the question because I twice prompted for a clarification.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, comment's upvote doesn't get counted. upvoting answer gets counted. upvote the answers which you think helped you, if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to have completely different action - NOT extended action of sorter

Then you have a two step procedure:

1. Disable sorting on the specific column. This is done by using  `setSortable(column, false)` method of the `DefaultRowSorter`.
2. Enable a different action when clicking on the table header. This is done by adding a MouseListener to the table header.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement your own `RowSorter` and in the `toggleSortOrder` method you would need to allow your column with 4 options to toggle to a new sort that the other columns wouldn't have.

To update the display you could extend the `DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer` class and add other sort order items beyond the ones that exist today.

Snippet from the class:

```
   SortOrder sortOrder = getColumnSortOrder(table, column);
             if (sortOrder != null) {
                 switch(sortOrder) {
                 case ASCENDING:
                     sortIcon = UIManager.getIcon(
                         "Table.ascendingSortIcon");
                     break;
                 case DESCENDING:
                     sortIcon = UIManager.getIcon(
                         "Table.descendingSortIcon");
                     break;
                 case UNSORTED:
                     sortIcon = UIManager.getIcon(
                         "Table.naturalSortIcon");
                     break;
                 }
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question. I want to change behaviour of one out of four headers.

Comment: I did misunderstand that you only want this change to effect one column.  However, I think the basic answer is still the same.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I am interested in seeing how do you change behaviour of individual column headers.

Comment: Sorry, after your edit I still can't see how do you get a single header and assign a different sorter...

Comment: You assign an entirely new sorter to the Table.  In that sorter your implementation of the toggleSortOrder method should control what is available.

Comment: But I don't want other headers to behave differently, just one - I want it to have completely different action - NOT extended action of sorter, for example I want to open a Message Dialog on click on that ONE header.

Comment: Then when you implement that method don't let the toggle on the row sorter do anything for the column alone, and then capture the mouse click elsewhere for displaying a dialog.

Comment: Would you be able to show code on how to assign the sorter to a single colum as opposed to the table?

Comment: The column is a parameter so it would just be an if() statement.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn, if i understood you correctly you want one(or more) of the specific column to have no sorting and on clicking do other action. the way is to use `SortKeys`. I had to write answer to show you in `code`